# My account is gone? Was it deleted? Why?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

My account is (or at least was): https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169330
But now for some reason it is gone. All my old questions are still there but now they say "user(some weird number)" instead of my name, and you can't click the profile. This suggests my account got deleted, but why? 
This is on all my stackexchange profiles, not just math stackexchange.

I would give more information, but I haven't done anything that could even be close to breaking a rule, ever. My last 2 posts were on Code Golf stackexchange and they were "Code close to the challenge: Sum of integers" and "Code close to the challenge: Inception"

So why was it deleted? Can I get it back?

Comment: You've been sent an email about this; please check it. This account will have to go now too

Comment: I have not been sent an email about this yet, are you sure its the right one?

Comment: I think only a mod or CM can answer this question, so take this speculation as speculation, but: if you are being sincere when you say you didn't break any rules, and never received feedback or notification from the mods or CMs that you were breaking the rules, and you yourself didn't request your account be deleted, then it's possible your account got hijacked and was used without your knowledge to either break the rules (eg by a spammer) or to request its own deletion (this last scenario seems unlikely to me, except as a prank by someone you know personally).

Comment: @Dan I think, looking at the dupe Shog pointed this towards, it was deleted because (s)he was under 13 :/...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Ah, that makes sense (my comment was made before the dupe was flagged).